# Erro ao fazer consulta

Tags: node.js, rest, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Estou construindo uma api rest com node, porem ao tentar fazer um get passando parametros retorna todos os dados.

app.js

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const url = 'url de conexao';
const option = {reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, reconnectInterval: 500, poolSize: 5, useNewUrlParser: true};

mongoose.connect(url, option);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Erro na conexao com o banco de dados! " + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', (err) => {
    console.log("Desconectado do banco de dados! " + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Conectado ao banco de dados!');
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const vendaRoute = require('./routes/vendas');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
app.use('/', vendaRoute);

app.listen(3000).on('listening', () => {
    console.log("Servidor rodando!");
});

module.exports = app;
```

vendas.js (route)

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Vendas = require('../models/venda');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Vendas.find({}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.send({error: "Erro ao realizar a consulta!"});
        return res.send(data);
    });
});
router.get('/:nome', (req, res) => {
    const nome = req.params.nome;
    Vendas.find({cliente: nome}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.send({error: "Erro ao realizar a consulta!"});
        return res.send(data);
    });
});
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const {cliente, produto, valorProduto, lucro} = req.body;
    if (!cliente || !produto || !valorProduto || !lucro) return res.send({error: "Preencha todos os campos!"});
    Vendas.create(req.body, (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.send({error: "Erro ao registrar! \n Tente novamente mais tarde!"});
        return res.send({message: "Registrado com sucesso!"});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

venda.js (model)

```javascript
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const VendaSchema = new Schema({
    cliente: {type: String, required: true},
    produto: {type: String, required: true},
    valorProduto: {type: String, required: true},
    lucro: {type: String, require: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Venda', VendaSchema);
```

Comment: Forneça um pouco mais de detalhes, por favor. Há algum erro? Qual o erro? Ou... Qual a saída esperada e o que você está recebendo?

Comment: Exemplo: ao ir em localhost/ me retorna todos os dados como deveria, ao ir em localhost/?nome=Lucas ele deveria me retorna todos que tem o nome Lucas, entretanto continua retornando todos os dados.

Comment: O seu código cria uma rota para localhost/Lucas, a rota localhost/ não trata a query da url

Comment: sim, foi isso mesmo, inclusive tinha respondido aqui mesmo, mas alguem apagou

Comment: @LucasSimao, sobre terem apagado, na [timeline](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/377206/timeline) da pergunta, é possível ver que foi removida por votação, provavelmente tinha algum problema com o conteúdo dela

Comment: vc precisa carregar os schemas na conexao. para fazer a consulta.